# Kinesis Data Stream GetRecords giving Junk Data

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis

While doing the  Getrecords from Kinesis Data Stream it is is giving values like `����Y�ݽ@��5���I$ݔѵ�����ս��aQ���̽�9������ռ��` intermittently. I have a large data and the Junk data comes in between the correct data.
My Code is Nodejs in Lambda and is triggered by SQS (which is a DLQ of an upstream lambda that process the Kinesis Stream) . This lambda is expected to do the reprocessing logic of the failed messages of the upstream lambda.
Any suggestion would be very helpful. Thanks.
Sample Data :
`{ "Attribute1" : "Value with over 400 charcters available ����Y�ݽ@��5���I$ݔѵ�����ս��aQ���̽�9������ռ�� . to make it work" , "Attribute2" : "value2" , "Attribute3" : "value3"}`

```
    var getKinesisRecords = async function (shardIterator){
    var getParams = {
      ShardIterator: shardIterator,
      Limit: 1
    };
 await kinesis.getRecords(getParams, function(err, result) {
      if (err) {console.log(err, err.stack); return null;}// an error occurred
      else { 
      try {
            for (var record in result.Records) {
                var data = result.Records[record].Data
                console.log("Kinesis Record data"+data);
            }
        } catch(err) {
            console.log("Error while getting Record from Kinesis");
            console.log(err);
            return null;
        }
           if (result.NextShardIterator) getKinesisRecords(result.NextShardIterator);
      }         // successful response
       
    }).promise();
    //Process the record
```

}

Comment: What is the code you have to put and to get records?

Comment: @luk2302 Added code